# How to mark a field as readonly when we clone a record?

Tags: page-layout, clone, read-only

I want to mark a single field as read only when I clone a record. I am not able to find which page layout is in action when we clone a record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible way to accomplish this is to use a validation rule.

While validation rules are not well suited to handle things of the form "*prevent all fields from being edited except for fields x, y, z*", validation rules can fairly easily handle locking down single fields.

In this case, using the `ISCLONE()` function in conjunction with `ISCHANGED()` should accomplish what you're looking to do.

Comment: Thanks Derek, that helped. validation rule option worked.

Answer (score 2):

One way I can think of to accomplish this would be to assign a different recordtype to the cloned record. With the different recordtype, you can associate a new page layout to it (one that has your target field marked as read-only).

Of course, that either requires you to be cloning via Apex (so you can modify the recordtype prior to insertion), or having a trigger in place that checks `isClone()` (a method of the [sobject class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm))